# Nokogiri failed to build gem native extension (RuntimeError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I am trying to install Nokogiri using:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

This is the mess that follows the installation:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
  --with-zlib-dir
  --without-zlib-dir
  --with-zlib-include
  --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
  --with-zlib-lib
  --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
  --with-iconv-dir
  --without-iconv-dir
  --with-iconv-include
  --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
  --with-iconv-lib
  --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
  --with-xml2-dir
  --without-xml2-dir
  --with-xml2-include
  --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
  --with-xml2-lib
  --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
  --with-xslt-dir
  --without-xslt-dir
  --with-xslt-include
  --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
  --with-xslt-lib
  --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
  --with-libxslt-config
  --without-libxslt-config
  --with-pkg-config
  --without-pkg-config
  --with-libxml-2.0-config
  --without-libxml-2.0-config
  --with-libiconv-config
  --without-libiconv-config
/Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
  from /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
  from extconf.rb:166:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/micahsherman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I would appreciate some tips or advice.  I am using Ruby 1.9.4, Rails 3.2.13 and I cannot figure out why this isn't working.  I am using Mavericks and I thought that might be the problem.

I have updated xcode, etc.

Comment: You've installed the XCode command line tools from XCode components or the command line?

Comment: As @PeterGoldstein said check if command line tools is installed. Go to Preferences | Downloads and under Components made sure Command Line Tools is checked. Also, I don't think you need the sudo.

Comment: "Check the mkmf.log file for more details" so what does your `mkmf.log` have to say?

Comment: Well there's about 13 mkmf.log files. What should I be looking for? Also, in XCode, under Preferences/Downloads, there wasn't any option for Command Line Tools.

Comment: Also it is updated to XCode 5.  I don't know if this makes a difference or not.  By the way I am still fairly new to programming, so I really appreciate y'alls help.

Comment: Why are you trying to install Nokogiri into your System Ruby? *NEVER* use `sudo` with RVM, even if it's a multi-user install, which it shouldn't be on a Mac OS system.

Comment: Well I tried running a regular gem install and it responded with "Permission denied", and then I looked at the nokogiri docs and it said to type "sudo gem install nokogiri".

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct solution but setting you up in the right direction. `rvm` is pretty solid at resolving its own issues. Follow these steps and help `rvm` do its magic

run `rvm requirements` to find what is missing.

use `rvm pkg` (on old version of rvm) or `rvm autolibs` to install missing packages.

Make sure you read all the documentation `rvm` asks you to read in this process.

Once done successfully, try installing `nokogiri`.

Comment: having the same exact problem while using rvm

Comment: It doesn’t have to be a “direct solution”. Following your steps solved a similar issue on my machine. A working solution is the most important thing. Thanks.